# ExtractByMask with one mask and multiple layers ArcMap?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst

I have a multiple cost distance rasters and multiple feature layers. I need to find and join the feature layers (or associated shapefiles) that lie within a threshold of costs on the cost rasters. For this, I have a loop which goes:

```
def joinfun(row, start, end):
    FID=str(row.getValue("FID"))
    where = '"FID" =' + FID
    out_fl='out_fl{0}'.format(FID)
    for FID in range (start,finish): 
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc,out_fl,where) #i want acodist_{0} to cycle through all the codist layers, while out_fl stays the same
        if arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management((arcpy.sa.ExtractByMask('codist_{0}'.format(range(start,finish)), out_fl)), "MINIMUM") <= threshold:
            arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis('out_fl{0}'.format(), out_fl, '"joined_{0}".format(FID) "and" out_fl') ##the format() should be the number of the codist_{0} which passed the condition, so that the out_fl is the one which is considered joinable 
            arcpy.Delete_management('out_fl{0}'.format(FID))
            arcpy.Delete_management('out_fl')
```

the issue here is the if statement. I need to find a way to see if the out_fl lies over an area of cost which is <=threshold, no matter the cost layer. Therefore, in the following statement, something needs to be done about the codist_{0}.format(range()) part:

```
if arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management((arcpy.sa.ExtractByMask('codist_{0}'.format(range(start,finish)), out_fl)), "MINIMUM") <= threshold:
                arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis('out_fl{0}'.format(), out_fl, '"joined_{0}".format(FID) "and" out_fl')
```

I need it to use the all codist_{0} rasters I have (from 4910 of them, from 0=0 to 0=4909) and check each for each out_fl (also 4910 of them in total). Does anybody have experience in or advice on this matter?

the SpatialJoin_analysis of the statement is the most important, because in the end, it is the goal of this process. I need to join all out_fl{0} that fall within the cost distance threshold of the next. the cost distance rasters are the accumulative cost at each cell leaving from out_fl{0} outwards.

Comment: I notice that this question has not been answered or commented upon in over two years.  I think that it is already in quite good shape but to try and attract an answer I think it would be worth reviewing http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312 for a couple of extra hints on writing and presenting code snippets (rather than just functions).